# is ROS navigation on C# possible?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS team. Congratulations for all your work on ROS. I’m currently developing some software in Windows using an iRobot Create and a Kinect. I’m particularly interested in the navigation methods that you have included on ROS. However I’m using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 with C#. I was wondering if I could add some .dll to my program to reuse the two steps of your navigation. Those would be:

1. Building a 2D map.
2. Use that 2D map to navigate my robot to a certain location.

Best regards,
Antonio

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12679/is-ros-navigation-on-c#-possible?/) by [Robotp38](https://answers.ros.org/users/1665/robotp38/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-01-18

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS currently is not compatible with C#

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2012-01-19**:
If you're willing to wrap the code yourself, it's possible in theory.  But the question was "can I add a .dll to my program" and use it in a C# program; the answer to that is no, because no one has written C# adapters for ROS, let alone the navigation stack.

**Comment by [raahlb](https://answers.ros.org/users/966/raahlb/) on 2012-01-18**:
As long as you only need a few message types exposed, it should be possible to write a wrapper DLL in C++ that could be loaded in a C# application, shouldn't it? Or is there some incompatibility somewhere? We're currently trying to do this at my company, so I'd love to know if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There exists a c# wrapper for ros. It is called roscs. Have a look at [ros.org/wiki/roscs](http://ros.org/wiki/roscs)

---

Originally posted by [Carpe Noctem](https://answers.ros.org/users/4732/carpe-noctem/) with karma: 21 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2